# Extracting Data from Child Elements and Using it in Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a generic directive that I want to use to display a flexible, spreadsheet-like data entry form.

I'd like to put all data structure & formatting information in the html code and have the directive take that and store it in the scope for later use.

Here's a sample HTML I'd like to use (the information in the "field" elements is what I'd like to get into the scope):

```
<array title="Breakdown" data="data.breakdown">
  <field type="text" default="" name="descr">Description</field>
  <field type="number" default="0" name="price">Price</field>
  <field type="number" default="0" name="tax">Tax</field>
</array>
```

And the directive so far

```
.directive('array', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: "js/array-template.html",
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      var x=transclude(tElement);              
       return function(scope, element, attrs) {  //the linking function
       scope.title=attrs.title;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The variable x gives me an array of html elements but it has not only the "field" elements but a bunch of empty "span" elements too. I could work with that if needed but I suspect that there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: The first time you will have access to scope is in your linkingFunction. You also have access to the element so theoretically you could search the element, pull values, and assign them to scope. However this just feels messy. Can you get the data into a better format, like JSON? If so you could pass it as an attribute to the directive, pull your needed values from that, and inject the necessary items into your template.

Comment: @bennick Thanks! Yes, that would be a solution but not desirable. It would be mixing a different syntax into the HTML markup. I wanted to keep description of the element in HTML. After a lot of searching I found the solution and posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

First I've use the last example on the AngularJS website main page: 
http://angular.github.io/angularjs.org/#/list
Which was good to start but the rendered HTML code always contained some junk because I had to use the ng-transclude directive to have the `<FIELD>` elements processed too.

So I looked further and found some examples of dynamically created templating. That gives a lot more flexibility and I could do a complete rewrite of HTML without any old piece showing up in the resulting code.

I also had to use a different method of communicating between the directives because the method used in the AngularJS website (shared controller) broke down when no ng-transclude was used in the main directive's template. 
I used just an added property to the module object, since both directives belong to the same object.

Here's the full code of the solution. I hope it will be useful for some people.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="flexlist">
        <array title="Breakdown" data="record">
            <field type="text" default="" name="descr" title="Description"></field>
            <field type="number" default="0" name="price" title="Price"></field>
            <field type="number" default="0" name="tax" title="Tax"></field>
        </array>
        <array title="test" data="record">
            <field type="text" default="" name="descr" title="Description"></field>
        </array>

    </body>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></SCRIPT>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></SCRIPT>
</html>
```

Javascript with ample comments ;-)

```
function record(){  //a simple constructor to provide the data for the table
    return [{
          descr: "example",
          price: 10,
          tax: 0.07
      },
      {
          descr: "something else",
          price: 15,
          tax: 0.11

      }
  ];  
}

var mod=angular.module('flexlist', []);
mod.fields=[];  //container that is shared between directives
//the directive for <ARRAY>
mod.directive('array', function($compile){  //injecting the $compile service
    return {
        restrict: 'E',  //restricted to element only
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            title: '@title'  //getting the title attribute into the scope
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attr){
            //calling the function specified in the "data" attribute 
            //which should return the data to be filled into the table
            scope.source=window[attr.data]();  
            scope.fields=[];  //preparing the "field" variable in the scope
            //copying the data collected from the <field> elements into the scope
            angular.copy(mod.fields,scope.fields);   
            //preparing the collection for the next use 
            //(in case more than one <ARRAY> block is in a page
            mod.fields=[]; 
            newCont=angular.element(   //creating the template's HTML
'<FIELDSET>'+
    '<LEGEND>{{title}}</LEGEND>'+
    '<TABLE border=1>'+
        '<TR>'+
            '<TH ng-repeat="fld in fields">{{fld.title}}</TH>'+
        '</TR>'+
        '<TR ng-repeat="line in source">'+
            '<TD ng-repeat="fld in fields">{{line[fld.name]}}</TD>'+
        '</TR>'+
    '</TABLE>'+
'</FIELDSET>');
            //applying the Angular "magic" -- the directives in the template
            $compile(newCont)(scope);  
            element.replaceWith(newCont);  //replace the whole <ARRAY> element
        },
        controller: function($scope, $attrs){
            // nothing here yet
        }
    };
});

mod.directive('field',function(){
    return {
        require: '^array',  //the "^" means that <FIELD> has to be inside <ARRAY>
        restrict: 'E',  //restricted to be an element only
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){ //collecting the data from the element
           mod.fields.push({  //pushing the data into the collection object
               type: attrs.type,
               'default': attrs['default'],
               name: attrs.name,
               title: attrs.title                 
           });
        }
    };
});
```